# Получение звука воспроизводимового на колонки

Tags: c#, аудио

Каким образом можно получить звук, который воспроизводится на колонки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наиболее правильным вариантом (и одновременно - наиболее сложным вариантом) было бы написание драйвера, который бы добавил в систему дополнительные виртуальные колонки...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Звуковой поток с устройства воспроизведения можно перехватить, например, с помощью:

- DirectShow;
- Сторонних библиотек (многие, если не большинство, основаны на том же DirectShow, только работать с ними несколько проще);
- MS MM API.

Средства для работы с DirectShow уже есть в .NET. Стороннюю библиотеку под .NET нужно сперва найти. Про MS MM API в .NET, к сожалению ничего не могу сказать.

В любом случае, это три основные направления в которых можно начинать копать.

Comment: Ну вот например teamviewer какую технологию использует для получения звука не знаете?

Comment: Этот вопрос, ИМХО, лучше задать разработчикам  teamviewer.

Comment: ну я просто хотел бы потом его отправлять в интернет как в teamviewer :D

Comment: А, ничего особенного в том, что это закрытое ПО и применяемые в нём решения защищены патентным законодательством? Может лучше разработать своё решение для онлайн трансляций?